# SQL script troubles

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve employeeIDs using the following sql script:

```
SELECT * from tblEmployees
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeeID10
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT employeeID
    FROM tblEmployees
END
```

The script runs but returns the entire table with all of the columns' names: employeeID, lastName, firstName, Comment. However, it should only return the employeeID column, no? Am I making an obvious mistake? I am using SQL server management studio 2014. Also, whenever I modify a script and try to re-run it again, I get an error saying that the script already exits. Is there a way to simply edit the script and re-run it with the same name?
Thank you!

Comment: You have a stored procedure, not a script.  Those are two different things.  You can't modify an existing stored procedure with the CREATE statement - you need to use the ALTER statement.

Comment: @TIm Thank you very much! I am new to SQL and greatly appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Am I making an obvious mistake?" yes, I'm afraid so, the first select statement is returning everything, an the second is creating a stored procedure.  My best guess is that you want this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeeID10
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT employeeID
    FROM tblEmployees
    --my guesswork come further and I added next line
    where employeeID = 10
END
GO

EXEC spGetEmployeeID10
GO
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to SQL, and I am actively learning! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is two different operations going on.

The first is your select * which will return everything.  The second is the stored procedure creation, which will not return anything.  That is why you are seeing the select * results and not the results that are in the stored procedure query.